# JS_malloc vs malloc

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

Is JS_malloc only used to allocate memory for javascript types in Spidermonkey?

If I need to allocate memory for a third-party datatype (not a JSObject or similar), is it ok to use malloc?

**What are the differences between JS_malloc and C malloc?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JS_malloc` is just there because it is guaranteed to use the same allocator as the Spidermonkey itself does, which may not be the same allocator as `malloc` in your code.  In particular some popular OSes (e.g. Windows) support separate heaps with separate allocators per shared library; if you're dynamically linking to Spidermonkey then calling Spidermonkey's `free` on memory you `malloc` in your code would crash.

So if you're going to deallocate the object yourself, you can use either `malloc`/`free` or `JS_malloc`/`JS_free` as long as you're consistent.  It doesn't matter much which one you use, unless you have specific requirements on which DLL's heap you want it to live in (e.g. you plan to unload the Spidermonkey DLL at some point while some of these objects are live).

If you're doing the allocation but expect Spidermonkey to do the deallocation, you need to use `JS_malloc`.

Comment: Is deallocating in the class finalizer what you mean by Spidermonkey doing the deallocation ?

Comment: @Mad, Spidermonkey doing the deallocation is when it makes the actual `free()` call.  For example, if you plan to allocate string memory that Spidermonkey will then free itself, you should be using `JS_malloc`.  If the `free()` call is happening in code you wrote yourself, then you're the one doing the deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if JS_malloc() fails, it calls JS_ReportOutOfMemory(cx) or similar, which can be used by error reporters etc.

Comment: This should be not an answer. You should post as comment rather.